# Reducing this summation in a recurrence relation

Tags: summation, recurrence-relations

I'm reviewing some of the solutions for the CLRS textbook by Cormen... For practice and I'm stuck on a recurrence embedded inside a summation.

\begin{aligned}
T(n) &=1+\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} 2^{j} \\
&=1+\left(2^{n}-1\right) \\
&=2^{n}
\end{aligned}

I'm not sure how they came out of the summation to obtain $ 1 + 2^n - 1$
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I see now
They used the geometric series.
So
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} x^{k}=\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}$$
$=1+\frac{2^n-1}{2-1}$

Then we use this and it reduces to the desired output